# OLAP Cube deployment failure due to connection to server

Tags: visual-studio, ssms

Everything worked from creating a database on SSMS, created everything on Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Don't know how to put the BI tools on visual studio 2017 in case someone knows that too) and when I tried deploy got this:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       The project could not be deployed to the 'localhost' server because of the following connectivity problems :
A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.
To verify or update the name of the target server, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, select Project Properties, click on the Deployment tab, and then enter the name of the server.          0
```

The server name in deployment properties is localhost as i have been using all the time until now.

Any ideas? Thanks